# Dijit ContentPane does not render a frame or frameset

Tags: frame, dojo, frameset, contentpane

I came across a problem today when I trying to render content from an external source into a 
dijit.layout.ContentPane.

```
  HTML
  <div id="someId"></div>

  JS
  var cp = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({}, "someId");
  htmlFromExtSrc = "<frameset> <frame src="http://www.google.com"></frameset> 
                    Other Data ";
  cp.set("content", htmlFromExtSrc);
```

What gets set in the html is only **OtherData**. Frameset and frame do not showup in the html.

I aim need to show the content from an external site rendered into the Pane correctly. Using Iframe solves the problem but I am looking for a better solution.
Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: simply put, dont use frames.. its so yesterday imo

Comment: I agree with not using frames. But what i want to achieve really is to be able to render content from an external source correctly, whether frames or no frames is not in my control.

Comment: Try dojox.layout.ContentPane. It parses script tags etc.. Thing is, at some point you will hit a `domnode.innerHTML = htmlFromExtSrc;` - and this is not at all the same as `iframe.contentDocument.write(htmlFromExtSrc);`